# Athena table location with equal signs in S3 key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create a new Athena/Iceberg table in my existing S3 directory structure. The location contains equal signs, e.g. `country=all/data`. These equal signs are escaped by Athena, which results in a table at the location `country%3Dall/data`.

*Example query*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.testtable (
    id bigint,
    value float) 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/country=all/data/mytable/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'table_type'='ICEBERG'
)
```

results in a table at `s3://my-bucket/country%3Dall/data/mytable/`.

Escaping the location (`country\=all`) in the query does not work either, as this just adds another escaped character in the path: `country%5C%3Dall/`.

**Question:** How can I create a table under a key containing equal signs?

Comment: Avoid the problem entirely by using a dash? Or `country/xyz/data/...`?

Comment: I'm aware that would be a technical possibility, but I still hope there is a way to make this happen.

Comment: I would try using Glue to scan the folder and see what it does. Alternatively maybe something with [partitioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html#creating-a-table) can be done here. Other than that I would recommend to ping support here